# Securely uploading data to Parse

Tags: ios, security, parse-platform

I have an iOS app that requires a license which can be bought from the AppStore through In App Purchase, and I store it in Parse. The problem is, that any user that checks the source code can easily see how the update is made once the purchase from AppStore is complete, and therefore is able to upload the license even without purchasing the license from the AppStore.

Currently I create a PFObject with the license information in the App Store callback function providing content, and I simply upload the PFObject to Parse. What I am scared that might happen is that anyone can find the keys in the source code to connect to my app data, then log in with their credentials, and simply copy over the function updating the license and setting the expiry date to somewhere far in the future.

Any way to overcome such a thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches you can take. If the license information is always going to be the same, you can store it in a .plist file that you can add to your .gitignore or an equivalent for your host.

If you do not need to upload your source code anywhere, you could also just keep it to yourself or manually delete that license for the uploaded version.